# What is the difference between constant variables and constant values in Dart?

Tags: dart

Dart has something I haven't seen in other languages:

```
var foo = const [];
final bar = const [];
const baz = [];
```

In the first case, while the variable itself is not constant, its value is.

Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time on this, I think I understand:

Lets say you have:

```
var foo = const [];
final bar = const [];
const baz = [];
```

You can change the value of a non-final, non-const variable, even if it used to have a const value:

```
foo =  [1, 2, 3]; // Was const []
```

This is useful in the case for operations where the values should not be updated. For example, say you need a variable to represent the days of a month:

```
month = const [1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]; //For February
```

Since the days in February is constant, we do not wish for anyone to change the days in the month. Hence in this case it makes sense for the value to be constant.

At some point, the same variable may need to be reused to represent a different month. In this case we can do:

```
month = const [1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]; //For March
```

In this case, the value of the variable is changed, *but the value itself is constant.* This is important in cases where you do not want to value to be modified. For example, doing `month.add(32)` would result in a script error.

The following two cases are what we're used to:

```
final bar = [1,2,3];
const baz = [];
```

A `const` variable is intended to be a compile time constant.
A `final` variable is one which is intended to be set just once, and not changed after that.  Hence a final variable can be set at run time in the constructor, and not changed after that.